# How to pass a service to an EmptyInterceptor class?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-mapping

```
public class Auditing extends EmptyInterceptor {

    @Resource
    private ApplicationService applicationService;

    public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializable id,Object[] currentState,   Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types) {   
        if(applicationService == null){
            System.out.println("applicationService is null");
        }

        return(true);
    }

}
```

I observed for each hibernate action a new Auditing object is getting created and in onFlushDirty() it is always printing " applicationService is null "

Can anyone tell me how can i make ApplicationService available in an EmptyInterceptor?

Comment: How do you register Auditing bean in the Spring?

Comment: I do not know how to register a bean in spring for Auditing. I was trying to catch entity property value change action and create a user understandable text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a work around for this by having a Class with static applicationService property.
Now by creating a static reference for it i can use applicationService.

Its working for now.. Please post any better or efficient suggestions if you have :)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class with application context object by implementing ApplicationContextAware interface.

```
public class ApplicationContextProvider implements ApplicationContextAware {
    private static ApplicationContext context;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return context;
    }

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ctx) {
        context = ctx;
    }
}
```

Now you can obtain your bean using below code.

```
applicationService = (ApplicationService ) ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext().getBean("applicationService")
```

Above code can be used to obtain any other bean in future and would not require you to keep adding static beans.